# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Tags: swift, uitextview, exc-bad-instruction

I know that there are a lot of questions about this error, but I haven't found solution for my problem, even if I read most of them. In view controller I'm trying to make my text view displaying top of text, instead of bottom of it. When there is only one textView, then everything works perfectly, but when I try do it with two of the, , then I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textViewA: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var textViewB: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    textViewA.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
    textViewB.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: Make sure both of your `@IBOutlet`s are wired up.  The circles to the left of them should be filled in.  If they are hollow, drag from the circle to the proper textView in your ViewController.

Comment: Your code works fine for me? Check your outlets.

Comment: They are connected fine

Comment: Maybe there is problem with some classes?

Comment: try removing them and adding them again.

Comment: @vacawama To be clear, sometimes the circles are empty despite things being wired fine.  This is pretty common when you're working in source control and you never open the interface builder files because just looking at them shows uncommitted changes...

Comment: @nhgrif, good to know.  What an annoying "feature".

Answer (score 1):

If your error is like this

[image: EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION]

Then it is because you have not hooked up your outlets, to do this go into the storyboard / nib and hook it up like so:

[image: NIB]

Make sure they are valid by seeing the circles become solid:

[image: solid]

Comment: I have two separate view controllers, not one with two text views :(

Comment: In that case @T.Chechelsk if you are reusing the view controller could you hook them up to the same outlet? Can you make a different view controller? Can you make the outlets optional by replacing ! With ? - what is your setup I think we need some more clues

Comment: My deafult class in this view controller was UIViewController, but I couldn't connect text to view controller so i changed class to View Controller

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. I tested it on my own. This is mostly an outlet error, if they aren't connected correctly. It could also be that you have removed an outlet from your code and still have it connected inside your storyboard.